# Horizontal scrolling when the width of browser's window is less than body/container (minWidth) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, horizontal-scrolling

I am struggling how to set `minWidth` for some `container/body/widget` to show horizontal scroll when the width of  browser window is less than container/body/widget (minWidth). Fo example Google has this feature:

[[image: with scroll - window less than content]

[[image: without scroll - window grater than content]

Comment: Yep. You should handle responsive layout. And adapt your app to screen size. Is not  desirable to have scrolls in app.